# How do I put a comma after each word of a specific line using a regex in notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a line not well formatted in about 1500 files and I plan to correct them in notepad++ with a regex. The thing is that I really suck at regex.

Let me detail my expectations:

Here is the line now:

`tags:: tree dog book razor`

And here is what I need:

`tags:: tree, dog, book, razor`

The regex should find the line and add the commas, last word of the line excepted. Some of the pages are well formatted.

I tried many many combinaisons of expressions, some worked in regex101, but nothing worked in notepad++.

Comment: Try [`((?:::|(?!^|\R)\G)\s*(?!\S+\s*(?:$|\R))\S+)` and replace with `\1`](https://regex101.com/r/XNR7IQ/latest)

Comment: Unfortunately notepad++ didn't find any string corresponding.

Comment: It sould support [continuation escape `\G`](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/searching/#regular-expressions) according to its documentation. Couldn't test it since it requires a Windows OS. (not sure how the referred *duplicate* remotely solves OP's problem but okay)

Comment: It works well in regex101 though... I don't understand why it's not working in notepad++

Comment: It actually works fine for me in notepad++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this regex:

```
(?:(?<=^tags::)|\G(?<!^))(\s*\w+)(?= )
```

This matches:

- `(?:(?<=^tags::)|\G(?<!^))` : **either**

  - `(?<=^tags::)` : positive lookbehind for start-of-string followed by `tags::`; **or**
- `\G(?<!^)` : end of the previous match (but not at the start of the string)
- `(\s*\S+)` : zero or more of spaces followed by one or more non-space characters, captured in group 1
- `(?=\h)` : positive lookahead for horizontal whitespace

Replace this with `$1,`.

Regex demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/LxbNQc/1)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It nearly does what I need! How do I tell the regex to modify only the line beginning with `tags::` ?

Comment: @Paul note you should include that information - that you only want to match after `tags::` - in your question

Comment: Many Many thanks for this. Yeah, I thought it was in the description, but it wasn't at all. Sorry, I should have made that clear.

Answer (score -1):

Regex Replace `/(\w)\s(\w)/` with `$1, $2`.

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/T4iIVL/1)

---

`\w` means any character that is treated as word - basically same as `[a-z0-9_]`
`\s` white space character

Comment: Quick question does \w work with accentuated characters?

Comment: @Paul No, just `[a-z]`. If you need other - you need to add them manually

Comment: @Paul: Yes it does, according to locale.

Comment: @Toto Is this specific to N++? Because _it depends_: https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html

Comment: @Justinas: From your link: `In most flavors that support Unicode, \w includes many characters from other scripts` and you can see it in action (using `.NET` or `rust`) [here](https://regex101.com/r/j8D3zQ/1)

Comment: @Toto And _again from same source_: Again, Java, JavaScript, and PCRE match only ASCII characters with \w. So it very depends on tool implementation

Comment: @Justinas: Sure but, in OP's case (i.e. Notepad++), `\w` matches letters with diacritics.